# Animating a border when class is applied?

Tags: html, css

How do we animate the change to a border that occurs when a class is applied.

For example:

```
el-item {
    border-left: 6px solid red;
}

 el-item.onSelected {
    border-left: 6px solid blue;
}
```

When the `onSelected` class is added to the `el-item` element, the border color changes to `blue`.  How do we animate that transition?

Comment: do you mean transition?
border property is an animatable property so you can just add a transition property the element , `transition: border 1s;`

Comment: Perfect!  That works.  Do you want to provide that as the answer so I can upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in css

```
.el-item{
    border-left: 6px solid red;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

and

```
.el-item.onSelected{
    border-color: blue;
}
```

I create a exemple here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/sauloduarte/pen/jOxgYJJ)

Answer (score 1):

border property is an animatable property so you can just add a transition property the element.

```
.class-name {
  transition: border 1s;
}
```

if you are adding and removing classes with js make sure that this property is set in a class that is not removed.